# PHP session.gc_maxlifetime at 7200 and not working

Tags: php, session-variables

In my .htaccess file:

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 7200
```

It is clearly set to 7200 seconds because if I run this in my PHP webpage:

```
echo ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime') . "<br>";
```

It will then show 7200. The default 1440 (24 minutes) is not long enough for my application. I'd like it to be 7200 (120 minutes) but I'm still losing my PHP $_SESSION variables after around 35-45 minutes after the user click on the submit button in a form. Before that time, everything works just fine. This is on a shared host with cPanel. I have session_start(); as the first code in my PHP webpage.

After the 35-45 minutes mark and after the user click the submit button, this is being triggered:

```
if ( isset($_POST['Save']) ) {
  if ( !(isset($_SESSION["alice"])) ) {
    $error = 1;
    echo 'Error with $_SESSION["alice"]';
  }
```

**Edit #1**

```
session.save_path = /var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php72
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
```

I've set session.gc_maxlifetime at 9 seconds and I can run the code below (in a file called z.php) for 50 minutes before clicking the submit button and the session variable is still set. Clearly, there's something I do not understand.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Montreal');
session_start();

echo "session.gc_maxlifetime = " . ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime') . "<br>";


if ( isset($_POST['Save']) ) {
  if ( isset($_SESSION["alice"]) )
    echo "Set: " . $_SESSION["alice"] . "<br>";
  else
    echo "Not set<br>";
}


$_SESSION["alice"]="bob";

echo date('H:i:s') . " " . $_SESSION["alice"] . "<br>";

?>

<form id="theForm" action="z.php" method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="Save" value="Save">
</form>
```

**Edit #2**

I set in the .htaccess, a maxlifetime of 7200, then I ran the code above "z.php", waited 70m and then clicked on Save and the next page said that the $_SESSION variable was not set. It is clearly not working. Yet, it worked with the maxlifetime set at 9 seconds for a 50m waiting time. Seems like the maxlifetime doesn't have anything to do with session variables.

**Edit #3**

I think I've figured it out. It is a shared hosting and the session.save_path is set only for my account but I have multiple websites on the same account, and as it is saying here:

```
https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime
Note: If different scripts have different values of session.gc_maxlifetime but share the same place for storing the session data then the script with the minimum value will be cleaning the data. In this case, use this directive together with session.save_path.
```

It it then logical that my other websites are cleaning the session variable. So I set the session.save_path elsewhere and now the session variable are set... forever... I think just need to figure out how to do the garbage collection. Even setting gc_maxlifetime at 1 second, the session variable are kept forever.

**Edit #4**

Not sure if this is the right way to do it but I made my own garbage collection command. A simple cron running every hour with:

```
/usr/bin/find /session-folder-somewhere -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +240 -print0 -exec rm {} \; >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Turns out that session.gc_probability is set by default at 0 on this webhost. I don't think it matter since a simple find and delete in cron should do the job. Now my sessions last between 4-5 hours which is just what I needed.

Comment: Check what the [`session.save_path`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) is set to. If that's a folder shared with other sites running on the server, the lower timeout settings those are using might be wiping your session files as well, if read access is configured laxly (which would also be a security issue.)#

Comment: And check the `session.cookie_lifetime` as well. If that is below your gc_maxlifetime value, then you still lose the session, because the client will simply not send the ID any more. (Assuming you are passing it cookie-based only, as you normally should.)

Comment: You wouldn’t need to reinvent the wheel if you had read the manual about file system session storage handling in PHP.